# Why is csv not defined?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to do a relatively simple parse of a csv file, and I don't understand why the csv module is not working. Here is my code:

```
import csv

def getFromCSV(fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        data = list(reader)
    return data

def append_row(fileName, my_list):
    with open(fileName, 'a') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow(my_list)


data = getFromCSV('dh_internal_all.csv')

for row in data:
    if '25252' not in row:
        print(row)
        append_row('parsed.csv',[row])
```

This returns:

```
dh-dfbhv2l:Documents jwr38$ python3 remove_bad_data.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "remove_bad_data.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = getFromCSV('dh_internal_all.csv')
  File "remove_bad_data.py", line 3, in getFromCSV
    reader = csv.reader(f)
NameError: name 'csv' is not defined
```

Thank you in advance for any tips.

EDIT: when I run `python3` in terminal, then `import csv`, and then `csv`, it seems to recognize it, it returns:

```
<module 'csv' from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/csv.py'>
```

Comment: Show python version and the output for "pip freeze | grep csv"

Comment: "Here is my code:" Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pasted the wrong code. In your traceback, the faulting line is 3, but in this code, it's 5 - the two missing lines are probably the "import csv" lines.

Comment: Yep you got it. I had moved my file, and then when I added `import csv` I was editing the old file in the old location. Oops. Thank you.